# How can I display the Excel Publish as PDF or XPS dialog using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I know I can use the following VBA to display the regular Excel (2010) Save As dialog (which is close), but how do I display the specific "Publish as PDF or XPS" dialog? This dialog limits the file types to PDF and XPS and is the one I am after, but there doesn't seem to be an enumeration for it in the `XlBuiltInDialog` enumeration.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
```

This particular dialog is accessed through the GUI by going to File -> Save & Send -> Create PDF/XPS Document -> Create PDF/XPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I still can't find any way of displaying this dialog using `Application.Dialogs`, however I can display it using this:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FileSaveAsPdfOrXps"
```

Works in Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work-around which could work for you.

1) Create a userform which asks whether the user would like to save as XPS or PDF. Create 2 buttons on the userform, one showing text "XPS" and the other showing text "PDF".

2) Add code to each button, so that when pressed, it will save the document in the format specified by the user.

In module with code:

```
userform_save.Show
```

In the xps button:

```
Private Sub cb_xps_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypeXPS, Filename:=filepath & xpsName
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

In the pdf button:

```
Private Sub cb_pdf_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filepath & pdfName
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I'm aware of ExportAsFixedFormat, however this doesn't help because there are a whole host of options that you can specify (like which page to publish, the quality etc, and so I would have to end up recreating the whole Publish as PDF or XPS dialog, along with options. That being said, your workaround is worth noting and may help others who want a simplified interface.